swiper.js parameters centeredSlides & slideToClickedSlide ignored
I set the following two
centeredSlides: false, // Disable centeredSlides      slideToClickedSlide: false, // Prevent auto-slide to clicked slide 
and yet, it always snap in and it does not stay where I swipe to.
Am I missing something with swiper.js API?

Look at the demo page what types of implementation are available: https://swiperjs.com/demos - Maybe freemode or scroll container could work - if you don't want snapping?

freemode NAILED it. Thank you for pointing it out. This issue is resolved. THANK YOU!
